# Retrieve google map coordinates from mySQL with 5 location in a row?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Assuming I have 5 locations in a row of data call locationOne, locationTwo, locationThree, locationFour, locationFive. How do i call all of them and show in google map in below ? Below show retrieve out one.

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $location['locationOne']; ?>,
map: map,
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what form do you store this `locationOne`, etc ? What is an output of your echo ?

Answer (score 0):

0 Create an array of all locations:

```
var locs = [
      ['Location name 1', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Location name 2', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5]

    ];
```

1. Display

   for (i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(locs[i][1], locs[i][2]),
           map: map
         });

Answer (score 0):

if $location is an array like $location['locationOne'], $location['locationTwo'], etc, use something like this:

```
<?php foreach($location as $location){ ?>
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location; ?>),
        map: map,
    }); 
<?php } ?>
```